# EclipseLink ValidationException - non-entity [class long] as target entity in the relationship attribute [field providerId]

Tags: java, jpa, glassfish, eclipselink

I received the following error when trying to deploy an an application to Glassfish.  Apparently there's something incorrect with my relationships.

Error from Glassfish Server when attempting to deploy:

```
        ValidationException Exception Description: [class edu...clinic.Treatment] 
uses a non-entity [class long] as target entity in the relationship attribute 
[field providerId]
```

Many-to-One relationship in my 'Treatment' class file:

```
@Entiity
... 
@ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "provider_fk", referencedColumnName = "npi")
    private long providerId;
```

One-to-Many relationship in my 'Provider' class file:

```
 @Entity
    ...
@Id
    @Column(name = "NPI")
    private long npi;
...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "providerId", targetEntity=Treatment.class)
        @OrderBy
        private List<Treatment> treatments;
```

I believe my annotations are correct, but something is amiss.  I'd appreciate any suggestions as to how to go about correcting this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following,
in Treatment entity change

```
private long providerId;
```

to

```
private Provider provider;
```

in Provider entity change

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "providerId", targetEntity=Treatment.class)
```

to

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "provider", targetEntity=Treatment.class)
```

Comment: Thanks... That seems to have resolved the issue, but now I'm faced with a ton of other errors from Glassfish... Back to the drawing board...